# How to subset words with certain number of vowels in rstudio?

Tags: r

I try to subset a list of words having 5 or more vowel letters using str_subset function in rstudio. However, can't figure it.
Is there any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: Need a [MCVE] and the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are evidently using stringr, the function str_count will give you what you are after.  Assuming your "list of words" means a character vector of single words, the following should do the trick.

```
testStrings <- c("Brillig", "slithey", "TOVES",
                 "Abominable", "EQUATION", "Multiplication", "aaagh")

VowelCount <- str_count(testString, pattern = "[AEIOUaeiou]")
OutputStrings <- testStrings[VowelCount >= 5]
```

The part in square brackets is a regular expression which matches any capital or lower case vowel in English.  Of course other languages have different sets of vowels which you may need to take into account.
If you want to do the same in base R, the following single-liner should do it:

```
OutputStrings <- grep("([AEIOUaeiou].*){5,}", testStrings, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: Upvote for your test case. You  should have corrected the impression given by the poster that `str_subset` was something that would necessarily be present in Rstudio. Does need to have a non-base package loaded.

Comment: This worked in RStudio:                                                            
str_subset(words,"([AEIOUaeiou].*){5,}")